# IOS iPhone app crash with [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] and _objc_msgSend_uncached

Tags: ios, iphone, logging, crash

Here is the crash report not sure why

```
Incident Identifier: 8F69B0C7-F57D-40C7-B8E7-7A846EDCFE2E
CrashReporter Key:   e18182a2b39e52acee70b63eb8a627bf2e6392ec
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:             androppo [1105]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EA41AE7C-D8E6-49E3-B124-6FDA7F51A4BD/androppo.app/androppo
Identifier:          buzoo.jp.roppow
Version:             1.1 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-10-22 12:36:38.195 +0700
Launch Time:         2014-10-22 12:36:37.387 +0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B410)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
```

Last Exception Backtrace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x25d69d62 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33949c72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x25d6f144 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184
3   CoreFoundation                  0x25d6d104 ___forwarding___ + 708
4   CoreFoundation                  0x25c9e934 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   androppo                        0x000def1c -[GADStatisticDictionary decrementNumberForKey:shouldNotifyDelegate:] + 68
6   androppo                        0x000d3f30 -[GADApplication init] + 588
7   androppo                        0x000d3cb8 __35+[GADApplication sharedApplication]_block_invoke + 40
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x33eaa40a _dispatch_client_callout + 18
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x33eb79e2 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 58
10  androppo                        0x000d3c88 +[GADApplication sharedApplication] + 148
11  androppo                        0x000cf810 +[GADSlot initialize] + 72
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3394a4c0 _class_initialize + 532
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33950042 lookUpImpOrForward + 250
14  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3394ff3a _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 30
15  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x339561f4 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 20
16  androppo                        0x000cd760 -[GADBannerView commonInitWithAdSize:] + 56
17  androppo                        0x000cd9e0 -[GADBannerView initWithFrame:adSize:] + 164
18  androppo                        0x000cdbbc -[GADBannerView initWithAdSize:] + 108
19  androppo                        0x0007a9d8 -[MainPageVC addBannerOfAdmob] (MainPageVC.m:810)
20  androppo                        0x00075bda -[MainPageVC viewDidLoad] (MainPageVC.m:105)
21  UIKit                           0x2920e700 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 596
22  UIKit                           0x292b85a0 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
23  UIKit                           0x292b84c8 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 224
24  UIKit                           0x292b7a4c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 60
25  UIKit                           0x292b7786 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 574
26  UIKit                           0x292b74ec -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
27  UIKit                           0x292b7484 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
28  UIKit                           0x2920bc1a -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 510
29  QuartzCore                      0x28c36f60 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 132
30  QuartzCore                      0x28c3294c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
31  QuartzCore                      0x28c327d4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
32  QuartzCore                      0x28c321c2 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 218
33  QuartzCore                      0x28c31fcc CA::Transaction::commit() + 320
34  UIKit                           0x2946fa58 -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 40
35  UIKit                           0x294707f0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2496
36  UIKit                           0x2947ac34 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
37  UIKit                           0x2946ec26 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 126
38  FrontBoardServices              0x2c4920dc __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 8
39  CoreFoundation                  0x25d30608 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 8
40  CoreFoundation                  0x25d2f8cc __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
41  CoreFoundation                  0x25d2e086 __CFRunLoopRun + 782
42  CoreFoundation                  0x25c7b97c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
43  CoreFoundation                  0x25c7b78e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
44  UIKit                           0x29272b82 -[UIApplication _run] + 554
45  UIKit                           0x2926d97c UIApplicationMain + 1436
46  androppo                        0x0007479a main (main.m:16)
47  androppo                        0x000746ac start + 36
```

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33faadfc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3402ad0e pthread_kill + 58
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f4a934 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33156bb8 abort_message + 84
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3317066a default_terminate_handler() + 262
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33949f0e _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3316ddec std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3316d5ac __cxa_throw + 108
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33949d46 objc_exception_throw + 246
9   CoreFoundation                  0x25d6f144 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184
10  CoreFoundation                  0x25d6d104 ___forwarding___ + 708
11  CoreFoundation                  0x25c9e934 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
12  androppo                        0x000def1c -[GADStatisticDictionary decrementNumberForKey:shouldNotifyDelegate:] + 68
13  androppo                        0x000d3f30 -[GADApplication init] + 588
14  androppo                        0x000d3cb8 __35+[GADApplication sharedApplication]_block_invoke + 40
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x33eaa40c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x33eb79e2 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 58
17  androppo                        0x000d3c88 +[GADApplication sharedApplication] + 148
18  androppo                        0x000cf810 +[GADSlot initialize] + 72
19  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3394a4c0 _class_initialize + 532
20  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33950042 lookUpImpOrForward + 250
21  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3394ff3a _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 30
22  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x339561f6 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 22
23  androppo                        0x000cd760 -[GADBannerView commonInitWithAdSize:] + 56
24  androppo                        0x000cd9e0 -[GADBannerView initWithFrame:adSize:] + 164
25  androppo                        0x000cdbbc -[GADBannerView initWithAdSize:] + 108
26  androppo                        0x0007a9d8 -[MainPageVC addBannerOfAdmob] (MainPageVC.m:810)
27  androppo                        0x00075bda -[MainPageVC viewDidLoad] (MainPageVC.m:105)
28  UIKit                           0x2920e700 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 596
29  UIKit                           0x292b85a0 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
30  UIKit                           0x292b84c8 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 224
31  UIKit                           0x292b7a4c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 60
32  UIKit                           0x292b7786 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 574
33  UIKit                           0x292b74ec -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
34  UIKit                           0x292b7484 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
35  UIKit                           0x2920bc1a -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 510
36  QuartzCore                      0x28c36f60 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 132
37  QuartzCore                      0x28c3294c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
38  QuartzCore                      0x28c327d4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
39  QuartzCore                      0x28c321c2 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 218
40  QuartzCore                      0x28c31fcc CA::Transaction::commit() + 320
41  UIKit                           0x2946fa58 -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 40
42  UIKit                           0x294707f0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2496
43  UIKit                           0x2947ac34 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
44  UIKit                           0x2946ec28 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 128
45  FrontBoardServices              0x2c4920de __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 10
46  CoreFoundation                  0x25d3060a __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 10
47  CoreFoundation                  0x25d2f8cc __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
48  CoreFoundation                  0x25d2e086 __CFRunLoopRun + 782
49  CoreFoundation                  0x25c7b97c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
50  CoreFoundation                  0x25c7b78e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
51  UIKit                           0x29272b82 -[UIApplication _run] + 554
52  UIKit                           0x2926d97c UIApplicationMain + 1436
53  androppo                        0x0007479a main (main.m:16)
54  androppo                        0x000746ac start + 36
```

This happened when I tried to run the app's .ipa through profile mode or window->devices, then drag the .ipa file to my device's app list. Yet It didn't happen if it ran in normal mode (cmd + r).  I have no idea about the crash log and what caused the crash happened. Could someone help me out, I must fix the issues today and submit to Itunes Connect. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.